# hybrid config Intel HD Graphics 530 + gtx 960M: can't get the proprietary drivers to work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, hybrid-graphics

I have a laptop with hybrid graphics, and I can't get my nvidia card to work with the proprietary drivers.

nvidia drivers installed:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-361                                      367.57-0ubuntu3                               amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-367
ii  nvidia-367                                      367.57-0ubuntu3                               amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.57
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-367                           367.57-0ubuntu3                               amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                    0.8.4                                         amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                 367.35-0ubuntu1                               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Xorg errors:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     5.771] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[     5.775] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[     5.796] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
```

lspci output:

```
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] [10de:139b] (rev a2)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] [1458:b456]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at de000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at df000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_367, nvidia_367_drm
```

/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:

```
[...]
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
alias nvidia nvidia_367
```

I also noticed that I get issues with nvidia-persistenced on boot:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
See 'systemctl status nvidia-persistenced.service' for details.
```

systemctl status nvidia-persistenced doesn't give me more information, but I noticed that in journalctl -xl I get the following line at some point:

```
nvidia-persistenced.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced: No such file or directory
```

Oh and also, I guess the output of lsmod could be useful here:

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_drm             16384  0
nvidia_modeset        765952  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              11489280  1 nvidia_modeset
drm                   368640  12 i915,nvidia_drm,drm_kms_helper
```

I am running ubuntu 16.10

```
Linux cerberus 4.8.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 11 14:03:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I had the same problems on 16.04.
With a default install, my machine doesn't work. I got cpu soft lockups all the time, by simply running the lspci command. In order to solve the cpu freezes, I had to install nvidia's proprietary drivers and blacklist nouveau. (even though in the end, the proprietary drivers aren't loaded).

I have really no idea what seems to be the problem here...
I really hope you can help me, in fact, I have this machine for almost a year now, and made multiple attempts to solve this issue, unsuccessfully... but didn't have time to dig deeper into this problem.
I really need to do some cuda programming, so it starts to be urgent, hence this post =)

Looking forward to your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Bumblebee? It's gonna to take a long time before nvidia releases any driver with Optimus support on linux plataforms. As we wait it's recommended to use [Bumblebee](https://bumblebee-project.org/install.html).